# How do i set the field widths of a GridView in C# and asp.net from database driven data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have data from a database in sql. This is being transfered into a GridView.

The problem is that the headers are all having variable widhts and look really odd. I have tried changing the properties of the GridView from the Properties View of the Rows and Header settings. However this doesnt make a difference.

I'm assuming that because the data is driven from a database, the widths are ignored.

Is there a way of fixing this?

Thanks

```
aspx:

<asp:GridView ID="gvLatestUpdate" runat="server" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="Double" CellSpacing="1">
<RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top"/>
<FooterStyle />
<PagerStyle />
<SelectedRowStyle />
<HeaderStyle BorderWidth="10px"/>
<EditRowStyle/>
<AlternatingRowStyle/>
</asp:GridView>

code behind:

SqlDataReader sdr = Business.DesignStandard.getDSGridInfo(Convert.ToInt32(ddlDateRange.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(UserID), headerName, DirectionOfSort);

gvLatestUpdate.DataSource = sdr;
gvLatestUpdate.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us the way you are setting the column width in the ASPX or aspx.cs file?

Comment: The source of the data shouldn't make any difference. The solution should just lie in the ASPX markup, so posting that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating the gridview with a known number of columns you can try the method below:

In the gridview markup create bound fields for every column which you are retrieving from the database and set the HeaderStyle-Width property of the bound item to the desired width

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmployeeId" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="EmployeeId" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdNumber" HeaderText="Id number" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Married" HeaderText="Maritial Status" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```